# Chrome extension onSuspend is never called

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I develop Chrome extension.

I try to add event listener to `chrome.runtime.onSuspend`, but it is never called.

I use the following code, but localStorage is not modified and there is no log messages in the console also (I use `--enable-logging --v=1` to save log messages to the file).

```
chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener(function() {
  localStorage["suspend"] = new Date();
  console.log("On suspend");
});
```

Test box: WinXP SP3 x86 with Chrome 28.0.1500.72 m

I've created test extension to easily reproduce this issue:

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Chrome onSuspend test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": { 
    "scripts": ["background.js"] }
}
```

`background.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener(function() {
  localStorage["suspend"] = new Date();
  console.log("On suspend");
});
```

Answer (score 12):

The `onSuspend` event is only triggered when the event page becomes inactive.

Because you didn't declare `persistent: false` in your manifest file, the background page is a [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html), not an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html). Consequently, the page will never become inactive, and the `onSuspend` event will never be triggered.

If you wish to turn your background page in an event page, use

```
...
    "background": { 
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't background page become inactive on browser close / extension remove or extension disable events?

Comment: How can I handle these events?

Comment: @Anton You can't. When the browser closes, all extensions are terminated without any notice.

Comment: @RobW, Is there a way to terminate the background page? Is there a `quit()` function?

Comment: @Pacerier `window.close();`

Comment: @RobW, As for event pages, how do we run code when `onSuspend` has resumed?

Comment: Hmm, it seems to re-run the entire  script thus disnecessitating `onResume` existence, then in that case, exactly what can be achieved by bg scripts that cannot be done with event scripts? Is there even a single use case for  a persistent bg script?

Comment: @Pacerier Background pages existed before event pages were invented. [The `webRequest` API cannot be used in event pages](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=447270), but other than that event pages are generally recommended.

Comment: @RobW, Cool, so *moving **forward*** we can say that when webRequest is avail for eventpages, bg pages will have zero usecases and will then be deprecated?